# how to get second highest number for multiple employee passed as parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table like
Emp_salary

```
Emp_id  Salary  name  Branch_ID  Is_Current_Branch  Branch_name
1       1000     A     89           0                pune
1       2000     A     25           0                Mumbai  
1       3000     A     12           1                Bangalore
```

here the Is_current_Branch indicated the branch where this employee working currently(Bangalore), if i want to get his branch where he was working before current branch(i.e. Mumbai) for all the employee whose ID passed through parameter in S.P.

```
@Employee='1,2,3' (3 employee parameter)
```

How to do... please help me out

Comment: What have you tried? Passing coma delimited value is an extremely bad idea. Use a table valued parameter instead.

Comment: Your current table design doesn't allow for that. There is no way to know if he worked in `Mumbai` before or after `pune` without you adding a `Date` or an `ID` to the table to sort on.

Comment: @DavidBrabant I am passing multiple employee value from front end and want to filter result for all employee whose id passed through front end.

Comment: Does the `Branch_Id` indicate the order, so did he work in Mumbai before because it's the next higher Branch_Id? Do you know how to split those Emp_id parameter or is it part of this question ?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Braanch_id would be in any order i just want to return previous branch for multiple employee.

Comment: -1 - It always amazes me that people expect me to spend my time answering questions they won't spend their time asking. (George)

Answer (score 1):

This query will give the second last branch of every employee if the current branch is not their first branch.

Op has not supplied any of the increasing field, so we are taking the records in the order of their increased salary.

```
;WITH secondbranch 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY emp_id 
                    ORDER BY salary DESC) AS branchnumber 
         FROM   emp_salary) 
SELECT * 
FROM   secondbranch 
WHERE  branchnumber = 2
```

Comment: @Romil Its quite good but i want to return previous branch for multiple employee whose id passed.

Comment: @SonamMohite - Just add a `AND Emp_ID IN (1, 2, 3)` but **beware** that this sorts on salary as explicitly mentioned by Romil. You **do not** want that but you haven't told us yet on what the data **can** be sorted.

Comment: @SonamMohite, Either send three parameters to represent three diff emp_id but it will be not feaisble if no of id's increased. So you will send a string splitted with comms(,). Now you can split that string in sp and use the values with the query posted by me. Refer http://forums.devshed.com/ms-sql-development-95/pass-a-list-of-integers-to-a-stored-proc-found-a-114179.html

Comment: Exactlly like what i want... Thanks... @romil could you please tell me that by number of employee id , how can i get previous branch for all employee.   i ll now give my exact problem

Comment: can u post the query in post.

Comment: @Romil  I have posted in answer... below  ... please cheek it

Comment: @SonamMohite, it means actual table name is HRMS_Employee_ServiceRecord and pk_ServiceRecord_ID is the sequential order of the employee branch. is it correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a Date field on the table (To ensure it is the correct entry) and then sort by it:

```
ALTER TABLE Emp_salary
ADD [LeftDate] DATETIME
```

Then you could select from Emp_Table:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM 
Emp_salary
WHERE IS_CURRENT_BRANCH != 1
AND Emp_id = 1
ORDER BY LeftDate DESC
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion, it sound good.. but could you please tell me how to return result for employee having employee id in 1,2,3

Comment: Change AND Emp_id = 1 to Emp_id IN (1,2,3) - you will have to change TOP 1 * too.

Comment: @DarrenDavies - Using TOP will only work for one employee but you can not make it work for several.

Comment: @Lieven - yes you are correct, OP would have to use UNION to join queries for multiple  employees into one set.  I think the basic principle is that he should be using a date field to ensure he gets the correct previous company.

Comment: @SonamMohite - *please help me out* - We love to but what about answering the questions we've asked?

Comment: @SonamMohite - No need to shout. Several people already inquired about what can be used as sortorder. Without an explicit sortorder, you will get random results at best.